# HTML/CSS: multiple successive full screen images

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

What's the best way of getting several successive fullscreen images that you can scroll through on one website?

I currently only have one image using the following code:

```
html {
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Do you know any JavaScript?

Comment: A little bit, but I tend to avoid it in favour of HTML/CSS if possible.

Comment: There are no pure CSS solutions

Comment: Do you only want to be able to view 1 image at a time? When you scroll, what do you expect to see? What do you expect to happen? Your CSS suggests you want to scroll, and then see a new image taking up the whole screen, but not see the transition of scrolling from one photo to another - is that correct?

Comment: This is a little complicated if you want to do it properly because you'll want to lazy-load the off-screen images or else this page will take forever to load with images of that size.

Comment: Change the background-image style on the html tag to avoid changing any of the other background style settings.

Comment: I'm not fussed if you can see the transition. I'm just after successive images (or blocks of text with a solid-colour background), only the first of which needs to be an image which takes up the whole screen.

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work using a little javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = ["imgurlone.jpg", "imgurltwo.jpg", "imgurlthree.jpg"];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if(i+1 < arr.length + 1)
    {
        i++;
        document.body.style.background = "url(" + arr[i] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
        document.body.style.background = "url(" + arr[i] + ")";
    }
}, 10000); // Runs every 10,000 ms or every 10 seconds
</script>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zDRZ/)

Generally speaking you should apply the background to the body instead of the HTML element

Comment: Curious, why do you say apply the background to the `body` over the `html` element?

Comment: Because in my demo it was giving me an error when I applied it directly to the HTML element and because it is more common to apply it to the body